# A question about angles in an irregular tetrahedron

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Given an irregular tetrahedron $ABCD$ with a circumscribed sphere.
This defines $4$ spherical triangles.
For the vertex $D$ these triangels are $ABD$, $BCD$ and $ACD$.
How to prove that
$$
\cos^2 ADB + \cos^2 BDC + \cos^2 ADC - 2 \cos ADB \cos BDC \cos ADC=1?  
$$

Comment: You are asking in the wrong forum.

Comment: Can this be migrated to Math Stack Exchange? I would give an outline of how to get the answer there.

Comment: I have moved it to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531153/spherical-identity-for-angles-in-an-irreular-tetrahedron.